# Which validation method to choose if the number of instances is limited?

Tags: cross-validation, model, model-evaluation

I have a question regarding how to measure the performance of a model when the distribution of instances per class is limited.

In my scenario I have five data sets $\mathcal{D}_{1}, \mathcal{D}_{2}, \ldots, \mathcal{D}_{5}$, where each $\mathcal{D}_{i}$ comprises of excatly 50 classes. Moreover, for each class within $\mathcal{D}_{i}$ there are exactly $\ell = 4, 5, 6, 8, 10$ samples ($\ell$ is fixed within each $\mathcal{D}_{i}$). For the sake of completeness, i'm using a simple Naive Bayes classifier.

Now to my problem: What sort of validation method is appropriate for this scenario? At the moment, I decided to apply LOO (leave-one-out), but I'm not happy with this, due to the long runtime. What are the other options? $k$-fold cross validation is only possible with a small and unusual $k$ (as typically $k$ is 5 or 10). But even if I would use a 4-fold cross validation, there would be only one class-sample in each fold. To my best knowledge, it would represent a stratified 4-fold cross validation, correct? So now I am asking myself if it does make any sense when each fold contains only one sample. Is there still a possibility for my model to generalize with this limitation? Should I stick to LOO?